# Extract a value using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Say I have this string: `fg_^"-kv:("value_i_want")frt`. That string will stay constant except for `value_i_want` - which could change all the time. This little string is hidden within a huge string of data (constantly changing), I have saved in a PHP variable

Is there any I could do a Regular Expression on a string, let's say of 50000 characters to find that string (above) without knowing what the value_i_want is, and then saving the value in a variable - using PHP

Comment: the size limit of searching through a string is only limited by the amount of memory your php installation has access to. You could do this pretty easy with something like: `/fg_\^"\-kv:\("(.*?)"\)frt/s`.

Comment: you want to say? this `fg_^"-kv:("......")frt` is a sub string of a 5000 word paragraph?

Comment: If the stuff on the outside is always constant, you can just use substr.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `strpos` to find where the value you want is. You may need to tweak this a little, I haven't tested it. `$long_string` is the string you are searching for a match in.

```
$start = strpos($long_string, 'fg_^"-kv:("', 0);
$end = strpos($long_string, '")frt', $start);
$value_i_want = substr($long_string, $start+11, $end-$start-11);
```

Comment: If the string is a constant, strpos usage is preferrable since it's way faster than preg_* functions.

Comment: `strpos()` doesn't seem to work when the string I'm looking for has quotation marks in it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(?<=fg_\^\"\-kv:\(\")[a-z_]+(?=\"\)frt)/', $yourstring, $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

Pattern: `(?<=fg_\^\"\-kv:\(\")[a-z_]+(?=\"\)frt)`

`(?<=fg_\^\"\-kv:\(\")` - positive lookbehind assertion, means that searched string should be after exactly this string: `fg_^"-kv:("`

`(?=\"\)frt)` - positive lookahead assertion, means the same, but before: 
`")frt`

`[a-z_]+` - the string you are looking for, may consist of one or more letter and underscores. Change it for your needs.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vS7dI0/1

Comment: The g modifier doesn't exist in PHP (when you want to find several occurences, you need to use `preg_match_all`). The m modifier is not needed since you don't use anchors. You should use single quotes for the regex string instead of escaping all the double quotes. No need to escape the hyphen outside a character class. You write "Change it for your needs" but what happens if there is no particular constraint on characters?